# send data from arduino sketch/adb (PC) to android

Tags: android, usb, arduino

I have to send text "Hello World" from arduino to android or android to arduino using android device and pc .I have installed Arduino ADK and trying to send via sketch to android device but unable to do so.I have tried the same approach via bluetooth and it works fine but unable to figure out the same via USB.
This is for Testing before implementing on the arduino board.

Summarizing:

1.How to send data from android to arduino via USB using PC /Arduino development Kit ?

Please point me to the direction I should be heading to solve the basic problem for testing .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are plenty of examples online. If you want an answer to your question, you need to specify what have you done to debug your issue.

Comment: @user2461391 Hello Sir,Thank you for looking into my query .I have tried bluetooth connection which works perfect but I dont know how to head towards the query above. I did not find anything for testing for the question asked above .If you can even post link for the query asked above then It would be of great help.Please guide me through the process.I really appreciate any Help Sir.Thank you.

Comment: Consider using plain old serial communications: https://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/

Comment: Thank you sir can I connect android to pc(arduino adk)and check the result on PC (For Testing).If yes then how do I do That ?? PLease guide me.Thanks.

Comment: That would be useless for testing. In Android<->Arduino communication, Android is the host, Arduino is the client. In PC<->Android communication, the PC must be the host.

Comment: Oh I see.How do I make pc host and send data to android ?? Is it possible and will that approach help ??Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Android ADK Board* and the right  adb library take here:

https://github.com/agoransson/microbridge-arduino

that will be easy after that.